# why is my Coldfusion stored procedure not executed in MySql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I'm using Coldfusion8 and trying to get a simple stored procedure to run a MySQL id-lookup.

When I fire the procedure from inside MySQL it's working. However on my Coldfusion page, nothing happens.

Here is my procedure:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_select_extern`(IN `iln_to_match` VARCHAR(13))
     LANGUAGE SQL
     NOT DETERMINISTIC
     READS SQL DATA
     SQL SECURITY DEFINER
     COMMENT ''
  BEGIN

      SELECT tn.iln
      FROM   teilnehmer AS tn
      WHERE tn.iln = iln_to_match
      LIMIT 1;
  END
```

And my procedure call in Coldfusion:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="proc_select_extern" datasource="dns">
   <cfprocparam type="in" value="#Session.Extern#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13">
   <cfprocresult name="extern">         
</cfstoredproc>
<cfoutput query="extern">
    <p>Hello #extern.username#</p>
</cfoutput>
```

I thought I would at least get a *CALL `proc_select_extern`('value');* report in MySQL, but I'm not even getting this.

**EDIT:**
So I got it to work on a empty page as a CFQUERY like so:

```
 <cfquery datasource="db" NAME="extern">
   SELECT tn.iln
   FROM teilnehmer AS tn
   WHERE tn.iln = #Session.Extern#
   LIMIT 1
 </cfquery>
 <cfdump var="#extern#">
 <cfoutput>#IsDebugMode()#</cfoutput>
```

Trying the same with a storedProc now.

Comment: A cfoutput loop is not a good litmus test. As Dave suggested, enable debugging so you can see any calls made to the database. Also, try cfdumping the whole query ie `cfdump var="#extern#"

Comment: @Leigh enable debugging by adding mode=debug to the URL? I'm also trying cfump. Thanks!

Comment: Debugging must be enabled in the CF Administrator (and your IP allowed).  To determine if it is enabled: `<cfoutput>#IsDebugMode()#</cfoutput>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some form of ColdFusion error message?  Also, if you have debugging enabled on the request do you see the procedure call being made there?

Also, just an observation.  The SQL in your stored procedure is very basic (single table select with no join).  Having this be a stored procedure will create more sql overhead than an inline query.  There will be no performance gain from using a stored procedure.

Comment: I'm getting a Coldfusion error, that "extern.username is undefined in VARIABLES". But I'm not sure the procedure fired at all, because shouldn't I get a CALL in MySQL?

Comment: regarding the storedproc: so I shoudn't convert this into a storedProc? I inherited this site and am still thinking on the best way to fiddle my way through (CF Newbie). I thought converting all queries to storedprocs would at least make the database "portable". This is a query I started with. There is a bunch of much more complicated queries which I don't dare touching yet (except cf-paraming all parameters, which hasn't been done)

Comment: If you are getting an error is it possible that the error is happening before the procedure call?  If so, the procedure call would not happen.

Comment: Converting to a stored proc doesn't add portability but actually limits it.  You are then locked into a database type (and maybe version).  Stored procedures should be used for complex data logic or to reduce database calls.

Comment: Ok. Little progress. If I run it as a query on a separate page I'm getting: Unknown column 'ABC' in 'where clause' when I try to pass in ABC as iln_to_match.

Comment: (Edit) Parameters do not work outside a procedure. Just hard code the value temporarily to see if it returns any records ie `WHERE column = 'ABC'`. You could also try calling the procedure from within cfquery. I *think* the syntax is `{ call procedureName ('ABC') }`

Comment: As far as converting to stored procedures, personally I would not make such sweeping changes until I was more familiar with the *entire* application. Wait until you have the whole picture, because what you learn later may affect your decision. Just my $0.02

Comment: @Leigh: I had designed the application on paper and had it developed for me, so I know pretty much every button. Back when I did it I had no exp front/backend, so I needed someone to do it for me. FrontEnd I can do myself now, so I started to delve into backend (CF, MySQL) to eventually be in charge of my own code. With my (still limited grasp) I can see a lot of things I wouldn't do as they are (security/performance). The above query runs on almost every page, so I tought just put it inside the DB. And I was practicing, too.

Comment: @DaveFerguson: works now. The error was not checking for recordcount=0, when continuing...

Comment: @frequent - Ah, okay. I thought you had inherited a completely unknown entity ;) Well there is not always a performance benefit to using stored procedures. I tend to use them for more complex stuff, and leave simpler sql statements alone. Keep in mind there may be other options. Like if you were just retrieving a userName, it could be done once per session, because username's don't usually change. But it all depends on the real app..

Comment: @Leigh: ok, I understand. The actually query wasn't for username but URL-external parameter, which I "could run in on every page" and need to tweak the layout depending on a valid parameter provided (global/user-based layout), so I'm setting and resetting a session variable with the external parameter and on the pages I need to query for user-based parameters, which I'm doing with this query. Once I get to my difficult queries, I'll ending back here (I'm afraid). So far, thanks for helping out. CFdump and Debugging do help!

Comment: @frequent - Yeah, I figured it probably was not that simple. Anyway, discovering sql debugging will definitely come in handy. So glad you solved this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a clear answer above.  I ran into the same issue and fixed it by editing the datasource in CF admin, and under advanced settings, checking off "Stored Procedures" in the allowed SQL section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
<cfquery name ="myQuery" datasource="mydataSource">
call sp_myprocedure();
</cfquery>
```

I have been looking for a solution for this error message for a while now and came up with nothing. I am on coldfusion 10 and my MySQL procedure runs fine when run on the MySQL server. Buy when I try

```
<cfstoredprocedure .....
```

it throws the following error:

> "Error Executing Database Query. User does not have access to metadata
>   required to determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can
>   not be granted, configure connection with
>   "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters
>   that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types."

I have tried setting up a JDBC connection with the above parameter but it didn't help either. So ended up passing a call to the procedure as a query which seems to work fine. Dropping the solution here for future reference.